# Android Studio – NSIS Error while installating

Tags: java, android, javascript, android-studio

I am trying to install Android Studio 2019 normally.  I downloaded the sources from the official https://developer.android.com/studio/.

Download done normally, but when I tried to execute the file, every time I get the error "NSIS Error":

> NSIS Error
>
> ---
>
> Installer integrity check has failed. 
>   Common causes include incomplete download and damaged media. 
>   Contact the installer's author to obtain a new copy.
>
> More information at:
>   http://nsis.sf.net/NSIS_Error

[image]
so I did the following with the same results.

1. Restarted my laptop, which runs Windows 10, Core i7, 8 GB RAM.
2. Turned off antivirus program, firewall and everything.
3. Tried CMD Solution "/NCRC.
4. Downloaded the source file three times (x64).
5. Downloaded the ZIP file (x64).

But nothing worked at all. 
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: "When all else fails, you will need to contact either the developers of the software you're attempting to download or your personal computer support channels. "